# creating a server for a project on android studio

Tags: android, sql-server

For my school project I need to think of an idea for a project on android studio that uses many components that were taught last year ex: taking pictures and GPS location.
My idea was that each user can post a picture of a place he visited once and to save his location with the photo and upload it to a server so that other users can see too and upload their locations as well.
The question is how can I create a server with a database that saves pictures, locations and usernames.
The scale of the server should be big as the project will be tested by no more then 2 phones or users.
I will be glad if the explanation will be simple as I am a novice in programming on android and never have I opened a server before.

Comment: You can use any laptop or computer as a server. the server is just a computing device that can handle network requests. Although you may need some special software that can handle that for you. you can try [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). There is a mode named 'put online' that makes it very easy to configure any laptop as a server. All you need is to know its IP address and write web services in PHP that handles requests and save/fetch data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) as Your backend as it is scalable and easy to implement.

Comment: And how do I use it in the application?
I will probably need access to the server or something of that sort